# How can I access a specific value from the dictionary returned by this object in Python

Tags: python, list

I have an object that returns the following list:

```
[[0, 'virtual_94', 
    {'sequence': 10, 
    'display_type': False, 
    'product_uom_qty': 1, 
    'qty_delivered_manual': 0, 
    'price_unit': 1000, 
    'discount': 0, 
    'customer_lead': 0, 
    'product_id': 1, 
    'product_no_variant_attribute_value_ids': [[6, False, []]], 
    'name': 'Produto de teste', 
    'product_uom': 1, 
    'analytic_tag_ids': [[6, False, []]], 
    'route_id': False, 
    *'tax_id': [[6, False, [**1**]]],* 
    'sale_line_exemption_id': False}]]
```

How can I access a specific value on this list? In my case, I need to access the value "1" that can be found on `'tax_id': [[6, False, [**1**]]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this.

```py
infos = [[0, 'virtual_94', {'sequence': 10, 'display_type': False, 'product_uom_qty': 1, 'qty_delivered_manual': 0, 'price_unit': 1000, 'discount': 0, 'customer_lead': 0, 'product_id': 1, 'product_no_variant_attribute_value_ids': [[6, False, []]], 'name': 'Produto de teste', 'product_uom': 1, 'analytic_tag_ids': [[6, False, []]], 'route_id': False, 'tax_id': [[6, False, [1]]], 'sale_line_exemption_id': False}]]

ID = infos[0][2]["tax_id"][0][2][0]
```

Comment: this worked exactly as expected. Thank you very much.

Comment: @pmatos A pleasure

Answer (score 0):

You can access lists with their respective indexes and dictionary values with their respective keys.

Here's a breakdown to get to your desired output:

```py
#Access the third element (index 2) in your initial list to get a dictionary
d = your_list[2]

#Get value for key 'tax_id' : [[6, False, [**1**]]]
tax_id_list = d['tax_id']

# Get sublist: [6, False, [**1**]]
tax_id_sub_list = tax_id_list[0]

# Get list with one in it: [**1**]
element_with_one = tax_id_sub_list[2]

#Finally, access the first element in that list: 1
print(element_with_one[0])
```

Outputs:

```
1
```

---

Merging all the above into a single line (however, harder to read):

```py
print(your_list[0][2]['tax_id'][0][2][0])
```

Outputs:

```
1
```

Comment: it did not worked exactly as expected but I get the idea. Thank you for your explanation.